# Windows 7 Service Pack 1 .exe from existing install?

Tags: windows-7

I find my internet to be un-reliable at the moment and to download the 1gb windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe will take the best part of a day! I have SP1 installed on my computer but need to slipstream SP1 with my install disk so I can install windows on my new SSD - so I need the above .exe.

Is there a way to extract SP1 from an existing install so I don't have to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't waste your time, downloading and slipstreaming the Sp1. Get a proper Windows 7 ISO which already has the Sp1 included from digital river:

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso

Download it from a friends PC or use a download manager where you can resume stopped downloads.

Comment: Thanks that is what I ended up doing.